# Documentation feedback: Recognize tags contribution from other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Yesterday I wanted to contribute to a tag so that it will become available, but I got the message that I got no upvote on that specific tag, so I can not contribute.

However I do have upvotes on this tag, but just not on Stack Overflow, but on a more specific Stack Exchange sister site, *[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could work without maintaining a list of tags for each site that has an equivilent (for this purpose) tag on another related site. Just because I know about `cake` on cooking.SE doesn't mean I know about `cake` on SO. (not sure if those tags exist, but you get the idea).

Comment: You could make the name of the tag public and hope some other guys with knowledge in this tag on SO are proposing to open the tag for Documentation. If however this doesn't happen and short of moderator intervention I would say it's not possible probably.